# Why my onclick can't trigger Animation Imageview

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, buttonclick

I want to make my Image View rotate to random angle by using Onclick(). But why the Onlick() works but the Imageview can't rotate?Here is my code.

```
ImageView rotate_plate;
Button debug_button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    debug_button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.test_button);
    debug_button.setOnClickListener(btngoOnClick);

}
private OnClickListener btngoOnClick = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        debug_button.setText("Click");
        rotate_plate=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.wheel);
        int stopturnnum = (int)(Math.random() *360);
        Animation am = new RotateAnimation(0, stopturnnum, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

        am.setDuration( 3000 );
        am.setRepeatCount(1);
        am.setFillAfter(true);
        rotate_plate.setAnimation(am);
        am.startNow();
    }
};
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27766722/how-to-randomly-rotate-an-image-in-android try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `ViewPropertyAnimator` API, it's way more convenient:

```
rotate_plate.animate()
    .rotation(angle)
    .setDuration(3000L)
```

Comment: It' works! thank you!
But how can I control it clockwise or anti-clockwise?

Comment: And how can I refresh my pictute when every time I hit the click?

Comment: I guess anticlockwise should have negative angle, for example -20. I don't understand your second question, what do you mean by refreshing picture?